# Exception in thread org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

this is my applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="studentbean" class="com.Student">
    <property name="name" value=" " />

</bean>
<bean id="JobA" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.Student" />
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="timeout" value="5" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="cronTriggerJobA"   class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="JobA" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/5 * * * * ?" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="JobA" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerJobA" />

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

i am using spring-2.5.6.jar and quartz-1.8.5.jar
when executing i am getting the  error

```
     Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
```

i was able to use Quartz scheduler without spring integration,but now i came across with this error anybody got a solution for this

Comment: Try to add SLF4J jar in the classpath

Comment: i have add slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar

Comment: Make sure all the transitive dependencies are added.

Comment: You need to add slf4j-api.jar in classpath. Check this out: http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

Comment: did you add all the dependent jars after adding the Spring jars ?

Comment: i have added all the dependent jars ,but still iam getting the error

Comment: After adding slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar, most probably you would have encoutered class-not-found exception for Log4j Logger class. Your applicationContext.xml works fine in standalone environment having quartz, spring, slf4j-log4j and log4j jars of required versions.

Comment: thanks it worked ,org/slf4j/LoggerFactory was not there in the jar what i have added,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks it worked ,org/slf4j/LoggerFactory was not there in the jar what i have added